# How to enable android shortcut badges by default in app settings

Tags: android, notifications, react-native, expo, vue-native

[App notifications settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvFMr.png)

I am creating an application on expo and vue-native. How to enable **show app icon badges** and **floating notifications** in settings by default after application install? Maybe some permissions? Do I need to detach my project to ExpoKit?